# openssl srp Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: openssl, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to make an TLS-SRP password verifier file for apache2 but running

```
touch password.srpv
openssl srp -verbose -srpvfile password.srpv -add -gn 1536 mirko
```

I get the folowing output/error

```
Trying to read SRP verifier file "password.srpv"
Database initialised
Database has no g N information.
140464325973656:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:175:fopen('password.srpv.attr','rb')
Enter pass phrase for mirko:
Verifying - Enter pass phrase for mirko:
Creating
 user="mirko"
 g="1536"
 N="<NULL>"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I was folowing this example: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/ssl/ssl_faq.html#srp

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

Comment: Does Apache have permission for the files `password.srpv` and `password.srpv.attr`?

Comment: yes, I also tried it with sudo, I did not create the password.srpv.attr file, if I create it I get almost the same output, only difference is "140460255950488:error:0E06D06C:configuration file routines:NCONF_get_string:no value:conf_lib.c:324:group= name=unique_subject" instead of "140464325973656:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:175:fopen('password.srpv.attr','rb')"

Comment: The error occurs when running the "openssl srp" command, I did not configure the apache side yet

Comment: I tried it on ubuntu 14.04(OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014) and it is working there, when I download the old version source code and run "make" how could I use it without running "make install"?